# How do I change css styles using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Although I'm normally able to make css styles for web pages, any change I try to make to css using AngularJS, even using `ng-style="xy"`, doesn't seem to change anything on the page.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="tableScrollPanel">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th ng-style="{
                    display: 'inline-block',
                    white-space: 'nowrap',
                    -webkit-transform: 'translate(0em, 0em) rotate(-90deg)',
                    -moz-transform: 'translate(0em, 0em) rotate(-90deg)',
                    -o-transform: 'translate(0em, 0em) rotate(-90deg)',
                    transform: 'translate(0em, 0em) rotate(-90deg)',
                    -webkit-transform-origin: '0em 0em',
                    -moz-transform-origin: '0em 0em',
                    -o-transform-origin: '0em 0em',
                    transform-origin: '0em 0em',
                    -ms-transform: 'none',
                    -ms-transform-origin: 'none',
                    filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    bottom: '0em\9'
                    }" ng-repeat="(key,headline) in model.headlines" ng-class="headline.classes" data-ng-bind="headline.name">
                {{headline}}
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="(key, row) in model.rows">
            <td data-ng-bind="row.title"></td>
            <td data-ng-repeat="(key2, column) in row.columns">
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="column.entry" ng-disabled="column.disabled"
                       ng-change="changeEntry(key, key2)">
            </td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="text-align: right">
    <button class="btn" data-ng-click="saveChanges()">Speichern</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use simple quote for property with a `-`

so for white-space it should be like :

```
'white-space': 'nowrap'
```

Comment: thanks, this is what confused me in the documentation, there are 2 style changes and one was with and the other without the single quotes https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: @LinuxNoob1337 Content of `ng-style` attribute is an [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) that evaluates to an object. This means that the object you provide needs to use valid JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Take the CSS out of the ng-style and create a CSS class and add that to ng-class.

It would be easier to read if nothing else.

What do you expect to happen? Also, what are you doing with ng-repeat in a th element?

Comment: This represents a matrix filled with data that is stored in a file and used across the webapplication. As this is not my code I have no clue wheater or not the implemented solution is the only/best way to achieve this

Comment: any text I write into it does not appear anywhere and the loaded text is not affected by my style as well, any clue why ?

Comment: ah, OK now I got it ng-class="headline.classes" ... that's why no changes did anything to it, thanks for the hint into the right direction, would give you a thumb up but don't have enough reputation